# I still get NaN even after converting calculations using parseInt

Tags: javascript, html, nan

I Need to print the calculations gotten from options inside the Gross input box(3rd box) but instead of the calculation, I receive NaN.

The answer should return gross pay calculations based on the function below.

If the hours worked are less than equal 40, the calculation will be inside the if condition, or else, a different calculation.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var hoursWorked;
  var hourlyRate;
  document.getElementById("hours").value = hoursWorked;
  document.getElementById("payrate").value = hourlyRate;
  if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
    var grossPay = parseInt((hoursWorked * hourlyRate)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("gross").value = grossPay;
  } else {
    var grossPay = parseInt((40 * hourlyRate + 1.5 * hourlyRate * (hoursWorked - 40))).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("gross").value = grossPay;
  }

}
```

```html
# Add A H1 Heading Of "Gross Pay Calculation"

<form>
  Hourly Rate:
  <select id="payrate" align="right">
    <script>
      for(var d=10;d<=60;d++) {
        document.write("<option>"+(d)+"</option>");
        d+=9;            
        document.getElementById("payrate").value;
      }
    </script>
  </select><br> Hours Worked:
  <select id="hours" align="right">
    <script>
      for(var d=10;d<=60;d++) {
        document.write("<option>"+d+"</option>");
        d+=4;
        document.getElementById("hours").value;
      }
    </script>
  </select><br>
</form>

Gross Pay: <input type="text" id="gross" align="right"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="GrossPay" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("hours").value = hoursWorked;
        document.getElementById("payrate").value = hourlyRate;` What do you think that is doing?

Comment: And submit buttons submit.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning your inputs to uninitialized variables change those to this

```
hoursWorked=document.getElementById("hours").value;
hourlyRate=document.getElementById("payrate").value;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script>
     function myFunction()
     {
         var hoursWorked;
         var hourlyRate;
      //hoursWorked= 
      hoursWorked=document.getElementById("hours").value;
        hourlyRate=document.getElementById("payrate").value;
        if (hoursWorked <=40)
        {
           var grossPay=parseInt((hoursWorked*hourlyRate)).toFixed(2);
           document.getElementById("gross").value = grossPay;
        }
        else
        {
           var grossPay=parseInt((40*hourlyRate+1.5*hourlyRate*(hoursWorked-40))).toFixed(2);
           document.getElementById("gross").value = grossPay;
        }

     }
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     # Add A H1 Heading Of "Gross Pay Calculation"

    <form>
    Hourly Rate:  <select id="payrate" align="right">
                  <script>
                  for(var d=10;d<=60;d++)
                  {
                    document.write("<option>"+(d)+"</option>");
                    d+=9;

        document.getElementById("payrate").value;
                  }
                  </script>
                  </select><br>
     Hours Worked: <select id="hours" align="right">
                  <script>
                  for(var d=10;d<=60;d++)
                  {
                    document.write("<option>"+d+"</option>");
                    d+=4;
                    document.getElementById("hours").value;
                  }
                  </script>
                  </select><br>
     </form>    


    Gross Pay:  <input type="text" id="gross" align="right"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="GrossPay" onclick="myFunction()">


     </body>
     </html>
```